# SQL to get the one to many mapping (like reverse CASE WHEN THEN END or decode in Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, mapping

For example,

Through "CASE WHEN THEN END" I can get a many-to-one mapping as below.

```
REGION = CASE WHEN IOG IN (1,2,14,37,72,101) THEN '1'
           WHEN IOG IN (11,22,48,77) THEN '7'
           WHEN IOG IN (7,13,18,24,39) THEN '3'
         ELSE NULL END
```

Currently, I want get the reverse mapping (one-to-many) which is used in WHERE clause, the logic is like as below (but it's not correct, what I mean is the logic)

```
CASE WHEN REGION = 1 THEN IOG in (1,2,14,37,72,101)
   WHEN REGION = 7 THEN IOG in (11,22,48,77)
   WHEN REGION = 3 THEN IOG in (7,13,18,24,39)
ELSE NULL END
```

There is grammatical mistake in above sql, but how can I make ? Is it possible to get a one-to-many mapping?

One more thing, which I'm using is Oracle DB, seems that it's not available by using "decode" because it's also one-to-one mapping.

Could anyone help with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN REGION = 1 and IOG in (1,2,14,37,72,101) then 1
            WHEN REGION = 7 and IOG in (11,22,48,77) then 1
            WHEN REGION = 3 and IOG in (7,13,18,24,39) then 1
            ELSE 0
       END) = 1
```

Or, you can get rid of the `case` entirely:

```
WHERE (REGION = 1 and IOG in (1,2,14,37,72,101) ) or
      (REGION = 7 and IOG in (11,22,48,77) ) or
      (REGION = 3 and IOG in (7,13,18,24,39) )
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the 2nd query (without CASE) will perform better?

Comment: @wdosanjos . . . On a full table scan, both are going to be about the same.  I'm not sure if Oracle is smart enough to use indexes for the second query.  I'm pretty sure it will not for the first.

Comment: Is the first one better than the second ? I don't have good knowledge on Oracle.

Comment: @jjs . . . The second would be considered better form.  It is simpler as a condition because it just contains basic conditions with `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Add Condition in where and using CASE .. WHEN .. THEN.. 
TRY TO FOLLOWING WAY..

select col1,col2,...colN..from Table 
Where clm1 = CASE WHEN **@PARAMETER** = 0 THEN **COL1** ELSE **@PARAMETER**

ONCE YOU SET SAME COLUMN NAME INTO WHERE CONDITION THEN YOU RETRIEVE ALL DATA FROM TABLE ELSE IF YOU WANT TO PASS AS PARAMETER THEN RETRIEVE BASE ON CONDITION VALUES FROM TABLE.